# Get the array set which has a distinct value for key PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(
        [0]=> array(3) 
            { 
                [0]=> array(3) 
                { 
                    ["name"]=> string(1) "a" ,
                    ["code"]=> string(3) "416" ,
                    ["id"]=> string(2) "a1" ,
                }, 
                [1]=> array(3)
                { 
                    ["name"]=> string(1) "a", 
                    ["code"]=> string(3) "522" ,
                    ["id"]=> string(2) "a2", 
                }, 
                [2]=> array(3) 
                { 
                    ["name"]=> string(1) "b" ,
                    ["code"]=> string(3) "580" ,
                    ["id"]=> string(2) "b1" ,
                }
            },
        [1]=> array(3) 
            { 
                [0]=> array(3) 
                { 
                    ["name"]=> string(1) "a" ,
                    ["code"]=> string(3) "416" ,
                    ["id"]=> string(2) "a1" ,
                }, 
                [1]=> array(3) 
                { 
                    ["name"]=> string(1) "a" ,
                    ["code"]=> string(3) "522" ,
                    ["id"]=> string(2) "a2" ,
                }, 
                [2]=> array(3) 
                { 
                    ["name"]=> string(1) "b" ,
                    ["code"]=> string(3) "899" ,
                    ["id"]=> string(2) "b2", 
                } 
            } 
    );
```

I have array like this. All I need is for each array (e.g [0]=>array())
I will search for the arrays inside and get the `array['code']` only for array set that has distinct name value.

Example for array[0]: I will get the `array[0][2]['code']` because the array set of this particular `array[0][2]['code']` has a unique 'name'

Comment: and what if all names in that array are equal?

Comment: And what if all of them are different?

Comment: compare them using for loop and flag

Comment: Make an array of all the names, and use `array_count_values`. Then find the one whose count is 1. Then find the element of the original array that has that name.

Comment: Do you need to know the position in the array or only the unique value?

Comment: No. It is not possible to have them different and equal..

Comment: @sauv0168 only the unique value. once you get the unique value then you will get the array set

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam how is that ? can you please show me how.?

Answer (score 0):

Assume in the below code `$array` is `$arr[0]` from your example:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "name" => "a",
        "code" => "416",
        "id" => "a1"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "a",
        "code" => "522",
        "id" => "a2"
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "b",
        "code" => "580",
        "id" => "b1"
    )
);

$counts = array_count_values(
    array_map(function (array $entry) { return $entry['name']; }, $array)
    // or array_column($array, 'name') in PHP 5.5+
);

$uniqueNames = array_keys(
    array_filter($counts, function ($count) { return $count == 1; })
);

$result = array_filter($array, function (array $entry) use ($uniqueNames) {
    return in_array($entry['name'], $uniqueNames);
});
```

Not necessarily the super most efficient method, but straight forward and functional. It filters the array down to the entries where `name` exists only once. This may or may not fit your definition of "unique", it's rather unclear what variations in the input data you may have.

Comment: Is it possible for a structure of array like my array on my question? When you echo for each name it is like `array[0][0]['name']`

Comment: I don't understand the question. The code above does the filtering for one nested array (e.g. `array[0][..]`). Just loop over the rest of your array to do the same there. Beyond that, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Can you make it for (e.g `array[0][0]['name'] `)  ? I don't really know how to do this kind of filtering

Comment: I think what you want to add is

 foreach($topArray as $subArray)
 foreach($subArray as $subSubArray)

and then put @deceze's code after that?

Comment: I was confused in variable names. for `$entry`, what array should it represent? for `array`.. is this a new array?

Comment: As I said, assume `$array` is something like `array(array('name' => .., ..), array('name' => ..), ..)`. Then the rest will fall into place. FYI, `$entry` will then represent one such `array('name' => ..)` array in the algorithm. But you do not need to worry about setting `$entry` to anything, just set the initial `$array`.

Comment: I have an error in array_map. `array_map(function (array $entry) { return $entry['name']; }, $array)`  for this line, I tried adding a comma but still I got error.

Comment: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: @Lew Then your array is not as expected. Again,let's assume all the output you're showing in your question is from an array called `$myData`, then `$array = $myData[0]`. Then it should work.

Comment: @deceze No sir, I think the error is from the array_map(function) as what is indicated on the error message. the line for `array_map`

Comment: @Lew That piece of code is throwing an error because the input data is not as expected. That's on purpose. The code expects to work with a certain data structure. If it doesn't get that, it'll error out.

Comment: @Lew I've added a concrete, runnable sample. See it work here: http://3v4l.org/32JUL#v530

Comment: @Lew I'll seriously leave that up as an exercise for you. There are several different examples of *mapping over arrays* in my code; learn what those actually do, then it's trivial for you to adapt that as necessary. The very first operation is essentially doing just that with the `name` key.